# Combining expression with operator &&

Tags: c#, lambda

I have class that works a bit like the Linq To Sql `Where` clause.

It builds a sequence of operations from an Expression tree.

The expression tree is an `Expression<Func<bool>>` (i.e. a lambda without arguments that returns a bool)

```
conditionBuilder.BuildCondition(() => x != 3 && y != 5);
```

The class works fine for `normal` expressions like the example above but now I need the functionality to combine expressions.

I have added And, Or methods like

```
var exp1 = () => x != 3;
var exp2 = () => y != 5;
var exp = ConditionBuilder.And(exp1, exp2);
```

but it gets complicated when combining several expressions.

I would like to write

`var exp = exp1 && exp2;`

but since I can't directly overload operator && I need to find some other solution.
The tricky part is that resulting operations does not have a boolean overload for the bitwise operators. i.e. the result of exp1 & exp2 is int and not bool. (I can get around this by adding `!= 0`)

So my questions now are:

- Will it be confusing if I let operator & be a logical expression (i.e. AndAlso)?
- operator && will work if I overload & / true / false but that will also create an implicit boolean conversion. I know implicit boolean conversion is something you want to avoid in C++ but I am not sure how it matters i C#. Also, should the overridden true and false evaulate the expression? (i.e. what should `if (exp1)` do?)

**Edit:**
I already have working code like this:

```
public class ConditionBuilder
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<bool>> _filter;

    public ConditionBuilder(Expression<Func<bool>> filter) {
        _filter = filter;
    }

    public static ConditionBuilder And(ConditionBuilder left, ConditionBuilder right) {
        return new ConditionBuilder(Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(left._filter.Body, right._filter.Body)));
    }

    public static ConditionBuilder Or(ConditionBuilder left, ConditionBuilder right) {
        return new ConditionBuilder(Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(Expression.OrElse(left._filter.Body, right._filter.Body)));
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**
to clarify the questions.

The expressions are converted into another format. An example is that `() => ConditionBuilder.IntField(123) == 5` is converted into `@123 EQ 5` (The real format is something else but you get the idea)

The problem is that the other format doesn't have a booleen overload for the bitwise operators. This means that `() => true & false` is converted into `True BITAND False` which is not a valid expression since it returns an int and not a boolean.

If I overload & to mean AndAlso

```
exp1 & exp2
```

is a valid expression but

```
() => x != 3 & y != 5
```

is not.

My second question was if having an implicit conversion to bool causes problems in C# like it does in C++.

Comment: With awareness of the fact that the expression library itself has `And`, `Or` etc, I'd be wary of choosing operator overloading instead, for the same sort of functionality. You say "it gets complicated when combining several expressions", but the operator overloaded equivalent, while more concise at point of consumption, is surely going to be harder to create and debug, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I would overload the `&` operator. This is not confusing since `&` can be logical or bitwise depending on the context.

To overload the `&` operator you will have to use a wrapper class (e.g. `ConditionBuilder`) for your overloaded operators.

You can see a full example overloading the various operators including `&` in the documentation for the true operator, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx.

---

A simple example using `ConditionBuilder` to demonstrate overloading the `&` operator).

```
void Main ()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    var exp1 = new ConditionBuilder (() => x != 3);
    var exp2 = new ConditionBuilder (() => y != 5);
    var exp3 = exp1 & exp2;

    Console.WriteLine (exp3.Execute ());
}

public class ConditionBuilder
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<bool>> _filter;

    public ConditionBuilder(Expression<Func<bool>> filter) {
        _filter = filter;
    }

    public bool Execute() {
        return _filter.Compile()();
    }

    public static ConditionBuilder And(ConditionBuilder left, ConditionBuilder right) {
        return new ConditionBuilder(Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(left._filter.Body, right._filter.Body)));
    }

    public static ConditionBuilder Or(ConditionBuilder left, ConditionBuilder right) {
        return new ConditionBuilder(Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(Expression.OrElse(left._filter.Body, right._filter.Body)));
    }

    public static ConditionBuilder operator & (ConditionBuilder left, ConditionBuilder right) {
        // Note this could confuse users for the problem discussed below.
        // Consider using Expression.And instead of AndAlso
        return ConditionBuilder.And(left, right);
    }

    public static ConditionBuilder operator | (ConditionBuilder left, ConditionBuilder right) {
        // Note this could confuse users for the problem discussed below.
        // Consider using Expression.Or instead of OrElse
        return ConditionBuilder.Or(left, right);
    }
}
```

I would be careful using short-circuiting operators (`AndAlso`, `OrElse`) with `&` and `|` as given `Foo() & Bar()`, when Foo returns false Bar will *not* be called which will be unexpected by most users.

---

### Alternative

Change ConditionBuilder's And/Or methods to be instance members and only take the right hand side as an argument.

```
public ConditionBuilder And(ConditionBuilder right) {
    return new ConditionBuilder(Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(_filter.Body, right._filter.Body)));
}
```

This gives a syntax such as `var exp3 = exp1.And(exp2);` which is neater than the original and will chain reasonably well `exp1.And(exp2).And(exp3)`.

You will have to be careful when mixing And/Or since `exp1.Or(exp2).And(exp3)` would give you `(exp1 | exp2) & exp3` rather than `exp1 | (exp2 & exp3)`. This can be avoided using explicit parentheses such as `(exp1.Or(exp2)).And(exp3)` vs `exp1.Or(exp2.And(exp3))`

---

### Problem with supporting &&

To support `&&` you will need to support the `true` and `false` operators in ConditionBuilder which will mean compiling and executing the expression.

```
public static bool operator true (ConditionBuilder left) {
    return left.Execute();
}

public static bool operator false (ConditionBuilder left) {
    return !left.Execute();
}
```

When testing this with LinqPAD the result from `var exp3 = exp1 && exp2` had less than ideal results.

1. exp1 had to be executed immediately to resolve the short-circuit.
2. When exp1 was true the resulting expression was equivalent to:
   `var exp3 = () => x != 3 && y != 5`
3. When exp1 was false the resulting expression was equivalent to:
   `var exp3 = () => x != 3`

Comment: That will not work since it will create a lambda and not an expression. See my edit

Comment: Sorry, I was just using `Func<bool>` because it is simple enough to write a short example, you can have & return anything, eg `return ConditionBuilder.And(lhs, rhs)`

Comment: I've changed the example to make use of your sample condition builder.

Comment: Are you sure that && evaluates as `if (lhs() == true) true else rhs()`? My guess would guess something like be `if (true(lhs)) operator&(lhs,rhs)`

Comment: So it is, I've fixed the answer. Through testing with linq pad it seems it is actually compiled as something like; `if (false(lhs)) lhs else operator&(lhs, rhs)`

Comment: I think you don't need to compile and execute the expression in `true()` and `false()` if you want `&&` to behave the same way as `&`, i.e. without short-circuiting.

Comment: Maybe not, you could always return true/false, though that to me seems odd since `var expr = new ConditionBuilder(() => false); if (expr) Foo()` would compile but would execute Foo when the user would probably expect it not to.

Comment: For me the short-circuit doesn't matter since I will never execute the expression. I just use it to build my own sequence of operations. In linqpad it seems like && will call false(lhs) and || calls true(rhs). This means that operator& would always be called if both true() and false() returns false. Is that defined behavior or implementation specific?

Comment: It is in the C# spec (7.12.2 User-defined conditional logical operators) but that means it's compiler specific. I can't see the advantage of using `&&` over `&` here since it requires an ugly hack to work and ends up calling the `&` operator anyway.